# Can I save an object graph to CloudKit?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I have a model A with a reference list to model B.

Is there any way to save A filled with B aside from creating A, creating each B element in the list one at a time, and then saving the reference list?

Even in the trivial case of a single association the saving is complex and not atomic.

Comment: Object graph like CoreData's Object Graph yup with this https://github.com/CloudKitSpace/CKSIncrementalStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have to save record A first because you need the recordId for setting the CKReference fields for all the B records. Then you can save all the B records in one operation by using the CKModifyRecordsOperation which has support for saving multiple items in one action.

Comment: A has a reference list of B. Is there a way for B to specify that it's part of the list in A?

I thought that for a `1:N` relationship only the "1" side specified the relationship.

Comment: Ah. Create A, create B, assign B in A, and use CKModifyRecordsOperation to save everything all at once. That seems to work fine.